# How to submit a form with jquery-ajax and update input on the form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jsp

How to submit this form with jquery-ajax and update ? In my servlet I can put some message as request's atribute or mb is better to put this massage to the response? How to update the class="valid-error"  with jstl or with success function of ajax?

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mainbutton").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) {
            console.log("before");
            $.ajax({
                url: "userctrl",
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serializeArray(),
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $('.valid-error').val(data.message.val())
                },
            });
        });
        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit the form
        console.log("after");
    });
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<form id="ajaxform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" />
    <p class="valid-error"> "SOME MESSAGE got with jstl or passed here with the ajax request" </p>
    <input id="mainbutton" class="mainbutton" type="button" value="trial" />
</form>
```

Comment: `val("data.message.val()")` you're setting the value to a string, not an objects childs value. Also, you need to `preventDefault()` or you risk page-refresh.

Comment: do u have any ideas?

Comment: val("data.message.val()") that's corrected but I dont see any letters there. Also I dont see console.log("success") in firefox or in chrome console ....